# Ingress service - different rewrites

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have ingress service with the fallowing config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-service
              servicePort: 3001
          - path: /auth/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-service
              servicePort: 3001
```

The thing is that when I'm running this on my minikube I cannot connect in a proper way, ie.
When I'm typing in the browser: `IP/api/test` it shows `not found` even though my express endpoint is:

```
app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  return res.send({ hi: 'there' });
});
```

But `IP/api/api/test` (double `api`) works and delivers expected response. Obviously I would like to get there with `IP/api/test`. How can I achieve that in my ingress config?

Answer (score 2):

If You want to access `http://.../api/test` by calling curl `http://.../api/test` than you don't need a rewrite for it so just make it empty.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-service
              servicePort: 3001
          - path: /auth/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-service
              servicePort: 3001
```

This configuration will for example rewrite the following:

```
http://.../api/test -> http://.../api/test
```

```
http://.../auth/test -> http://.../test
```

```
http://.../asdasdasd -> http://.../asdasdasd
```

---

Update:

In case You have another rewrite with `path: /?(.*)` You can modify Your app path request to:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  return res.send({ hi: 'there' });
});
```

and use the original ingress configuration You posted in Your question.

This way when the request You have issues with will be resolved in following way:

`IP/api/test` -> `IP/test`

This is also the reason why You experienced `IP/api/api/test` before. Because one `/api/` was removed by rewrite and then `IP/api/test` was accessible.

Yes, You can have multiple rewrites in ingress. As long as they don't loop or rewrite too many times.

Comment: That would be correct but then another ingress will take over as my frontend app has ingress which caches `path: /?(.*)` in the same node (GKE)

Comment: It means that I would need to have multiple (two) rewrites definitions. That however is not possible in one ingress config file, isn’t it? Can regex help here?

Comment: I have edited my answer to address Your additional questions. Sorry for delays caused by Christmas Holidays.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `rewrite-target` messing with your api link, change that to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` and you can directly communicate with the `/api/endpoint`.

As this [example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) explains it, and you can also see that it is appending the placeholder from your url with `rewrite-target: /app`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` did not change the behaviour, it is still the same

Comment: Is it working with `IP/api/api/test` even after applying the ingress? Could you describe the ingress and see if it has annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`.

Comment: No, `IP/api/api/test` is not working in this scenario as well

Comment: Ok, my bad. Could you please try by completely removing that `rewrite-target` annotation?

Comment: I tried with removing it and also both `IP/api/api/test` and `IP/api/test` does not work

Comment: This kinda worked for me: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/$1` but it is only for `api` but what if I'd like to use second path as well `auth`?

Comment: Ok gotcha, add `rewrite-target: /` and change path as `- path: /api` remove ?(.*). Can you check if this setting works?

Comment: Nope, unfortunalely it does not work. Not sure but I think they have changed how to write it those.